# Can we use For and Since together in the same sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I am not sure if my sentence is correct:

> I had worked at Delicious Cake shop for more than 2 years since February 2012.

I quit the job in July 2014.
The people at Delicious Cake shop were very nice to me.
But It always took me more than 2 hours to travel to the shop,
so I wanted to look for a job that is closer to my living place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not advising you on a cover letter, just on the grammar...

You would want to say something like this:

> I worked at Delicious Cakes for more than two years, **starting in** February 2012.

**since** would not work there very well, unless you punctuated the sentence like this:

> I worked at Delicious Cakes for more than two years—since February 2012.

But there, **since February 2012** is disjunct, and there is an ellipsis:

> ...  — [I worked there] since February of 2012.

In a different structure with more complicated tenses you could say:

> By July of 2014 I had been working at Delicious Cakes for more than two years.

That would be like telling a story, not simply giving the raw facts of your employment:

> By July of 2014 I had been working at Delicious Cakes for more than two years, and felt it was a good time to try something different.

Comment: But in verbal speech one would simply say "I worked at Delicious Cakes for more than two years since February 2012."

Comment: I disagree with @user1425, That sentence is not idiomatic.

Comment: But this one is idiomatic ""I worked at Delicious Cakes for more than two years - since February 2012."

Comment: @user1425. Yes, because "since February 2012" is really a separate clause with ellipsis/deletion, which would be reflected in a longish parsing pause after the word "years". "I worked at Delicious Cakes for more than two years ...  [I worked there] since February 2012."  The temporal phrase "since February 2012" is not part of the phrase "for more than two years".

Answer (score -1):

'For' and 'Since' can be used together. Usually redundant/duplicate words are avoid during sentence construction.
 In the mentioned sentence, its just the sentence structure that seems incorrect.