# The use of "for" and "since" in the same sentence in the past tenses

Tags: since

Who established that using **FOR** and **SINCE** in the same sentence is wrong? Is there any opinion of a grammarian on this matter or is it common sense, so to speak?

> I composed music for 10 years since I bought my first guitar.

I understand that the sentence is not correct. Here is one of the explanations I have had so far as to why it’s wrong:

> **Ago** is a starting point, before now.
> **For** is the duration.
> **Since** is both the starting and end points, shown by the tense.  So you cannot use '**since**' with '**for**'

But how can SINCE be the end point if we remove **FOR**

> "I composed music since I bought my first guitar"

It's not clear when I stopped composing music. And it can't be substituted for "I have composed music since..." because I am not composing music any longer.

**My first question: what is the reason, the logic behind the idea of the ban of using "FOR" and "SINCE" in the same sentence in the past?**

**THE WAYS TO AVOID THE PROBLEM.**

Do you agree that these are the ways to avoid the problem.

1

> I composed music for 10 years, since I bought my first guitar.

> I composed music for 10 years - since I bought my first guitar.

2

> I composed music for 10 years after I bought my first guitar.

> I composed music for 10 years beginning in the year when I bought my first guitar.

I know that a similar question has been asked but it wasn't answered in all details I need.

Comment: Related:[Can we use For and Since together in the same sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/175407/can-we-use-for-and-since-together-in-the-same-sentence)

Comment: There's no such ban. "Since" doesn't indicate an endpoint. Your source sounds bad. Can you cite a reputable source that states it?

Comment: None of your sentences are correct, but that's because to use "since" you need to use a perfect tense, probably present perfect if the speaker is still composing music.

Comment: Did you notice that I made it specifically clear in the title of the question that this question is about PAST TENSES?

Comment: Follow my examples. 1 I composed music. 2 I composed music for 10 years. 1 and 2 are correct so far. Now I want to indicate the starting point of my composing. 3 I composed music for 10 years since I bought the guitar. - You say 3 is wrong because a perfect tense must be there. OK. 3a I had composed music for 10 years since I bought the guitar. - But 3a is wrong because the PAST PERFECT doesn't make sense here.

Comment: _I composed music for 10 years after I bought my first guitar_ implies that the speaker has stopped composing. If they are still doing it, they might say "I've been composing music for ten years - ever since I bought my first guitar" where the second part is an afterthought.

Comment: Kate Bunting is a trouble solver unlike some others who are trouble makers.